# how to split last 2 digits of each value in the string array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have an array:

```
last7day = ["", 20191219, 20191220, 20191221, 20191222, 20191223, 20191224, 20191225]
```

I want to split the last 2 digits of them. I tried `last7day.split(-2)` like slice command but couldn't succeed.

**Desired output:**

```
last7day = ["", 19, 20, 21...]
```

Comment: What is the output you want, and can you include the actual code you have tried?

Comment: are you trying to split the element, or the array itself?

Comment: I need last 2 digits of those values as array like last7day = ["", 19, 20, 21...]

Comment: @KutayDeril have a look at my answer below then it does what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const last7day = ["", 20191219, 20191220, 20191221, 20191222, 20191223, 20191224, 20191225];
const arr = last7day.map(day => day.slice(-2));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to get the remainder of the division by 100:

```
last7day.map(x => x % 100)
```

If there are strings in your array you want to skip you may check if the values are numbers:

```
last7day.map(x => typeof(x) === 'number' ? x % 100 : "")
```

You really dont need to convert the numbers to strings and back.

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with a negative value as second parameter.

```js
var last7day = ["", 20191219, 20191220, 20191221, 20191222, 20191223, 20191224, 20191225],
    result = last7day.slice(0, -2);

console.log(result);
```

Same goes with strings as well.

```js
var last7day = ["", 20191219, 20191220, 20191221, 20191222, 20191223, 20191224, 20191225],
    result = last7day.map(s => s.toString().slice(0, -2));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think he wants to separate the last digits of each element hence this is not the answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

Change the number to string and then use `slice()`. Then you can convert your string value back to number using `parseInt()` or appending a `+` for that spliced result.

```js
var last7day = ["", 20191219, 20191220, 20191221, 20191222, 20191223, 20191224, 20191225];
var res = last7day.map((item) => item ? +(item.toString().slice(0, -2)): '');

console.log(res);
```

Comment: you didn't split them you removed them...

Comment: @EugeneSunic OP wants to get rid of the last two digits

Answer (score 1):

You can use *slice* function for this action. Please try below code .

```
var last7day = ["", 20191219, 20191220, 20191221, 20191222, 20191223, 20191224, 20191225];

const finalArray= last7day.map(day => day.slice(-2));

console.log(finalArray);
```

`finalArray` this will be your output

Comment: I used this as  var xAxis = last7day.map(day => day.slice(-2)); and it worked thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the last edit of the question:

```js
const last7days = ["", 20191219, 20191220, 20191221, 20191222, 20191223, 20191224, 20191225];

const getLast2Digits = e => {
  // directly return strings
  if(typeof e === 'string') return e; 
  // cast to string, then take last two characters and recast to number
  else return parseInt(String(e).substr(-2));
}

console.log(last7days.map(getLast2Digits));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to string and then use `substring` method:

```
const result = last7day.map(d => 
    [
        d.toString().substring(0, 4), 
        d.toString().substring(4, 6), 
        d.toString().substring(6, 8)
    ])
```

An example:

```js
var last7day = ["", 20191219, 20191220, 20191221, 20191222, 20191223, 20191224, 20191225]
const result = last7day.map(d => [d.toString().substring(0, 4), 
    d.toString().substring(4, 6), 
    d.toString().substring(6, 8)])
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const array = ["", 20191219, 20191220, 20191221, 20191222, 20191223, 20191224, 20191225];

const numArray = array.map(v => {
  if(typeof v === 'number') {
    const num = v.toString();
    const c = num.substring(num.length -2, num.length);
    return parseInt(c);
  }
  return v
});

console.log(numArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using substr method to get the last 2 digits

1. convert elements to string
2. get the last two characters of each element

```js
const last7day = ["", 20191219, 20191220, 20191221, 20191222, 20191223, 20191224, 20191225]

const result = last7day
  .map(x => {
    if (typeof x === 'number') {
      const y = x.toString();
      return y.substr(y.length - 2)
    }
    return x
  })

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like that

```js
let last7day = ["", 20191219, 20191220, 20191221, 20191222, 20191223, 20191224, 20191225]
    let newDays = last7day.map((i)=>{
      return  i.toString().substr(-2)
      })
    console.log(newDays);
```